# Apache Beam and avro : Create a dataflow pipeline without schema

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

I am building a dataflow pipeline with Apache beam. Below is the pseudo code:

```java
PCollection<GenericRecord> rows = pipeline.apply("Read Json from PubSub", <some reader>)
    .apply("Convert Json to pojo", ParDo.of(new JsonToPojo()))
    .apply("Convert pojo to GenericRecord", ParDo.of(new PojoToGenericRecord()))
    .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, schema));
```

I am trying to get rid of setting the coder in the pipeline as schema won't be known at pipeline creation time (it will be present in the message).

I commented out the line that sets the coder and got an `Exception` saying that default coder is not configured. I used one argument version of `of` method and got the following `Exception`:

```java
Not a Specific class: interface org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:285)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createSchema(ReflectData.java:594)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData$2.load(SpecificData.java:218)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData$2.load(SpecificData.java:215)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
    ... 9 more
```

Is there any way for us to supply the coder at runtime, without knowing the schema beforehand?

Comment: What does the pipeline do with the GenericRecord's downstream? Is it possible to simply not use GenericRecord?

Comment: @jkff it converts `GenericRecord` to `TableRow` and writes to `BigQuery`. It also uses `AvroIO` to write to file system (which is another problem I am facing btw, as `AvroIO` needs schema too).

Comment: What schema to you want the Bigquery table and the generated Avro files to have? It sounds like you're writing records with many different schemas, so I suppose they have to go into different tables and different files?

Comment: @jkff We are using schema evolution so both schema comply to the same BigQuery table. Just that one schema will have extra fields and other won't. We will insert `null` values for those fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. I recommend the following approach:

- Do *not* use an intermediate collection of type GenericRecord. Keep it as a collection of your POJOs.
- Write some transform that extracts the schema of your data and makes it available as a `PCollectionView<however you want to represent the schema>`.
- When writing to BigQuery, write your `PCollection<YourPojo>` via `write().to(DynamicDestinations)`, and when writing to Avro, use `FileIO.write()` or `writeDynamic()` in combination with `AvroIO.sinkViaGenericRecords()`. Both of these can take a dynamically computed schema from a side input (that you computed above).

Comment: Hey @jkff, thanks for your reply. A couple of questions : 
1. We have already implemented writing to BigQuery with `PCollection` of POJOs and it seems to be working fine.
2. Regarding the writing to files, could you please provide the pseudo code of how to write `PCollection<POJO>` to GCS with `AvroIO`? We tried exploring `FileIO` and `TextIO` but we are not able to figure out how `write()` or `writeDynamic()` methods would help.
`AvroIO` needs `PCollection<GenericRecord>` in order to write and we can't have it unless we apply transform on `PCollection<Pojo>` that requires a coder.

Comment: Especially a Pseudo code that explains how to write documents using `PCollection` and `PCollectionView` and `AvroIO` to dynamic destination would be great.

Comment: You need Beam 2.3.0 or later, and then you can use FileIO.write/writeDynamic() with AvroIO.sink() - see an example in the unit tests of AvroIO https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7aeb5858f5067a5e02f3a135f98ae931183c005c/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIOTest.java#L933